# a generic error occurred in GDI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razor

```
public static string DrawImage(string WorkDirectory, string oldImage, string WaterMarkImage, string waterMarkText, int XCoord, int YCoord, string NewImageName)
        {
            MemoryStream msNew = new MemoryStream();
            MemoryStream msOut = new MemoryStream();

            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(WorkDirectory + "\\" + oldImage);
            Bitmap bmpWm = new Bitmap(WorkDirectory + "\\" + WaterMarkImage);
            Bitmap bmpTemp = new Bitmap(bmp);
            Graphics canvas = Graphics.FromImage(bmpTemp);
            bmp.Dispose();
            try
            {
                using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmpTemp))
                {
                    gr.DrawImage(bmpWm, new Rectangle(XCoord, YCoord, bmpWm.Width, bmpWm.Height), 0, 0, bmpWm.Width, bmpWm.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMessage = "Error occurred during submission.";
               return errorMessage;
            }
            bmpTemp.Save(WorkDirectory + "\\" + NewImageName, ImageFormat.Png);

            bmpTemp.Dispose();
            return WorkDirectory + "\\" + NewImageName;
        }
```

Hi, this code is working fine in local server ,when putting this code on the live server than ,i am getting the error "a generic error occurred in GDI+".
    so how can solve this error.

Comment: GDI+ image manipulation and asp.net is tricky (from own experience), check inner exception, see http://alperguc.blogspot.in/2008/11/c-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi.html

Answer (score 0):

This error invariably arises because of a lack of permissions. The fact that it works in one environment and not another pretty much confirms that is the cause in your case. The user account under which the ASP.NET process is executing needs Write permissions on the location where you are trying to save the image.

The account you grant this permission to depends on the version of IIS you are using. For IIS 6 and 7 it is NETWORK SERVICE. From IIS 7.5 it is IIS APPPOOL\. You shoudl check with whoever manages your hosting server.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for you reply. i have changed all permission in server. . but i got again error"Access to the path D:\\...\\images\\image1.png is denied." .can you give me another solution.

Comment: Your error message confirms that permissions is still a problem. Double check the path and the user permissions.